# Comparing between data from a file and from a form fails even though it's the same

Tags: php

I have a problem with my webpage. I have this admin.txt file that contains "**foo**", and "**bar**" on the next line. Now on my webpage is a form where I must input two values, and when submitted will check if the values I inputted on the text inputs are equal with the values in the text file, but always returns fail even if i typed in the same values with the text file which is foo and bar. Check my codes:

index.php

```
<?php
<form method="post" action="check.php">
<input type="text" name="text1">
<input type="text" name="text2">
<input type="submit">
?>
```

check.php

```
$location = "txt/admin.txt";
if ( file_exists( $location )) {
$page = join("",file("$location"));
$txt = explode("\n", $page);}
$text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$text2 = $_POST['text2'];

if ($text1==$txt[0] && $text2==$txt[1]){
echo "success.";
}
else
echo "fail";
```

Comment: That code makes no sense: you're exploding into `$txt` but then comparing against `$img`.

Comment: Also always use `trim()` on data coming from files, there may be additional invisible line break characters

Comment: OK then try `trim()`: `trim($txt[0])`

Comment: works perfect, pls post it as an answer. ;)

Comment: Instead of join/explode/trim, you could also just try `$page = file("$location", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`

Comment: Oh hey, that's nifty! Didn't know that existed. Making my answer CW and adding that @mario

Answer (score 3):

There may be additional invisible line break characters that cause the comparison to fail.

In Windows for example, the line break is `\r\n`, meaning your `explode()` will leave the `\r` in the data.

Always use `trim()` on data coming from files.

Alternatively, you can also use the [`file()`](http://php.net/file) function with the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` parameter.